# Auto refreshing with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a simple question (or answered before), but could anyone tell me how to download a page with JScript? I want to use Javascript to download the page "example.php" on my server every five seconds and compare it with what it was before. If the page changes, I would like the Javascript code to refresh the page hosting the Javascript. Does that make sense ? Somethingl ike:

`string downloaded = DownloadPage("example.php");`

`timer x = new timer(5);`

when the timer goes off:

`if(DownloadPage("example.php") == downloaded){`

`RefreshPage();`

`}`

Thanks, and sorry this was probably such an easy question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery framework's [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function:

```
$.get('example', function(data) {
  if(data == "something")
     //perform action
});
```

Comment: A note to IMAPC: AJAX is required, but the jQuery framework is not.  You can use AJAX without a framework in plain JavaScript.  Personally I much, much prefer using jQuery, but just thought it should be mentioned :).

Comment: thanks Corbin and Trevor, that was pretty much exactly what I was looking for :P